# how to list all maven profiles defined in project including all sub modules?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have project with quite a few sub modules, I am just curious is it possible to list all profiles defined in project and sub modules by command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use `mvn help:all-profiles`. This command would list out all profiles in each project. And you can see more details at [Maven Help Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/all-profiles-mojo.html)